# How can I give files extended attributes in mac os x?

Tags: files, osx, xattr

How can I give files extended attributes in mac os x? Mac os x doesn't have the 'setattr' command.

Answer (score 5):

My *El Capitan* has no `setattr` or `setxattr` (the latter *is* the name of a C runtime function: you could make your own utility using that).

OSX provides [`xattr`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xattr.1.html), which (noting comments such as [Mac OS X Extended Attributes and Xattr](http://xahlee.info/comp/OS_X_extended_attributes_xattr.html)) seems fairly recent.  A comment in *[Manually set extended attributes on arbitrary files](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110102222441243)* from 2011 gives a hint about OSX 10.5

You can see some discussion in *[How do I remove the “extended attributes” on a file in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833052/how-do-i-remove-the-extended-attributes-on-a-file-in-mac-os-x)*, as well as a copy (no date) in [SS64](http://ss64.com/osx/xattr.html).  In looking for sources, I came across a [sourceforge project](http://xattr.sourceforge.net/) which may be relevant.  The best source of course is the manual page on *your* machine.

The manual page lists several formats, pointing to this one as the way to *set* attributes on a file:

```
 xattr -w [-rsx] attr_name attr_value file ...
```

where the `-r`, `-s` and `-x` options respectively deal with directory-recursion, symbolic links and *input* of the attribute value using hexadecimal.

Comment: Thanks, that xattr sourceforge project compiled perfectly for me on iOS 12.4, arm64, clang 10.0 jailbroken. I had been searching everywhere for a basic xattr cmdline utility like this that would compile, and nothing else worked, despite this project being last updated 13 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

As they say, *"there's an app for that."* You can download [`xattred` – a "full-featured extended attribute editor"](https://eclecticlight.co/xattred-sandstrip-xattr-tools/) and other related tools here. `xattred` is cloaked in a minimalistic GUI (and AFAIK is closed-source), but it's a quicker way to learn what can be done with extended attributes in MacOS. There are also open-source xattr editors for MacOS on GitHub; e.g. [xattr-editor](https://github.com/rcsiko/xattr-editor).

The command-line utility `xattr` bundled in MacOS is best-suited for scripting, and repetitive task.

Answer (score 1):

It's called `xattr` on OS X . You can use `setxattr` to set attributes.

Answer (score 1):

In MacOS Monterey, setxattr gives `zsh: command not found: setxattr`

Instead it is `xattr -w <attribute name> <attribute value> file/folder`.

Full manpage is here:

````bsh
$: xattr
Not enough arguments for option -�. Expected at least 1 but got 0

usage: xattr [-l] [-r] [-s] [-v] [-x] file [file ...]
       xattr -p [-l] [-r] [-s] [-v] [-x] attr_name file [file ...]
       xattr -w [-r] [-s] [-x] attr_name attr_value file [file ...]
       xattr -d [-r] [-s] attr_name file [file ...]
       xattr -c [-r] [-s] file [file ...]

The first form lists the names of all xattrs on the given file(s).
The second form (-p) prints the value of the xattr attr_name.
The third form (-w) sets the value of the xattr attr_name to the string attr_value.
The fourth form (-d) deletes the xattr attr_name.
The fifth form (-c) deletes (clears) all xattrs.

options:
  -h: print this help
  -l: print long format (attr_name: attr_value and hex output has offsets and
      ascii representation)
  -r: act recursively
  -s: act on the symbolic link itself rather than what the link points to
  -v: also print filename (automatic with -r and with multiple files)
  -x: attr_value is represented as a hex string for input and output```
````